# ADB error: protocol fault (couldn't read status): Undefined error: 0

Tags: android, macos, adb, macos-mojave

I'm trying to get adb to work on a macbook pro, but I can't get it right. I simply want to see the devices attached and continue from there, but I'm running into the most informative error message ever:

adb devices
* daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
* daemon startenter code hereed successfully
List of devices attached
error: protocol fault (couldn't read status): Undefined error: 0

What I've tried:
- Install android studio including sdk-tools

- Delete Android studio completely and manual install sdk platform-tools (Current state)
- Check .bash_profile for correct path (some left-overs still there. At the moment only the platform-tools folder exists):

```
export ANDROID_HOME=Users/r.dekker/Library/Android/sdk

export PATH=${PATH}:/$ANDROID_HOME/tools:/$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:/$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/
```

- start virtual device from android studio, doesn't run.
- A lot of google and stackoverflow searches. Didn't find anything that resembles my problem. Did find more logging. Does this make sense to anyone?

```
export ADB_TRACE=all
RichardMacbookPro:~ r.dekker$ adb devices
adb D 09-23 13:47:58  1671 41655 adb_trace.cpp:192] Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
adb D 09-23 13:47:58  1671 41655 adb_trace.cpp:192] Version 29.0.4-5871666
adb D 09-23 13:47:58  1671 41655 adb_trace.cpp:192] Installed as /Users/r.dekker/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb
adb D 09-23 13:47:58  1671 41655 adb_trace.cpp:192] 
adb D 09-23 13:47:58  1671 41655 adb_client.cpp:154] _adb_connect: host:version
adb D 09-23 13:47:58  1671 41655 adb_io.cpp:107] writex: fd=5 len=16 30303063686f73743a76657273696f6e 000chost:version
adb D 09-23 13:47:58  1671 41655 adb_io.cpp:81] readx: fd=5 wanted=4
adb D 09-23 13:47:58  1671 41655 adb_io.cpp:91] readx: fd=5 disconnected
adb: failed to check server version: protocol fault (couldn't read status): Undefined error: 0
```

- Vysor also doesn't recognise any device
- Used different devices, different cables

Does one of you have an idea about a log I can check, something I can try again? To me it looks like nothing works and I'm forgetting something. Any ideas?

Comment: Is it resolved, m also looking for the same

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
Disable Debugging option and enable again, check the USB port of android and clean it, same for cable and try again, and change mode from charging to file transfer.

Comment: Thank you for helping out. I have tried disabling and enabling the debugging option, checked and switched cable and device, changing mode, nothing helped. Because the error also is shown when no device is connected, I assume the problem lies earlier than when the device is connected. Does this make sense?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not on the device, but on the development computer.

I resolved the issue by updating my Platform Tools from the SDK Manager in Android Studio.

With the issue:

```
$ adb --version
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
Version 30.0.2-6538114
```

After upgrading:

```
$ adb --version
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
Version 30.0.5-6877874
```